# Prestashop, wget invoice

Tags: bash, prestashop, wget, prestashop-1.6, invoice

I'm trying to download invoice with bash script(wget), because I need to save invoices to my server automatically when order is made. I looked for other solutions but that didnt work, like downloading invoice with changing  tcpdf.php.The post was up here: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/465729-automatically-generate-invoices-in-a-folder/

So first I need to login to prestashop adminpage I suppose. Logging in got me confused, because how do I know when I'm logged in? This what I did:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'email=example@gmail.com&passwd=example' http://www.example.ee/admin/index.php?controller=AdminLogin&token=5a01dc4e606baa6c26e95ddea91d3d14
```

After saving my cookie, I tried to download the invoice by:

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -e robots=off -A pdf -r -l1 http://www.example.ee/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf&token=35b276c05aa6r5eb516437a8d534eb64&submitAction=generateInvoicePDF&id_order=3197
```

But I get an error: `Deleting, www.example.ee/admin/index.php?controller=AdminPdf, since it should be rejected`

I think It's because I'm still not logged in?

It would be very nice that if it's possible without wget.

PS changed my website to example,etc

Comment: Why don't you hook on the invoice creation and then upload the PDF to your server?

Comment: Please try using quotes around the URL. And maybe post the outputs when you run the 2 commands.